# How to convert 4-digit hexadecimal number to bcd in verilog testbench

Tags: verilog

```
`include "bcd.v"

module bcd_4(A,B,Cin,S,Cout);
input [15:0] A,B;
input Cin;
output [15:0] S;
output Cout;
wire w1,w2,w3;

bcd_adder U1(.A(A[3:0]),.B(B[3:0]),.Cin(Cin),.S(S[3:0]),.Cout(w1));
bcd_adder U2(.A(A[7:4]),.B(B[7:4]),.Cin(w1),.S(S[7:4]),.Cout(w2));
bcd_adder U3(.A(A[11:8]),.B(B[11:8]),.Cin(w2),.S(S[11:8]),.Cout(w3));
bcd_adder U4(.A(A[15:12]),.B(B[15:12]),.Cin(w3),.S(S[15:12]),.Cout(Cout));

endmodule
```

I have designed a 4-digit BCD adder using four 4-bit BCD adders.  The inputs 'A' and 'B' are taking hexadecimal values.  How can I write a testbench so that the input values should be decimal only? I have to check the following condition also:

```
if({Cout,S}==A+B+Cin) $display("pass");  
else $stop;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inputs of your adder do not take hexadecimal values. They are 16-bit inputs which represent 4 BCD digits of 4 bits each.  The input for each digit can range from 0 to 15 in decimal, but since they are BCD any value greater than 9 would be invalid.

The inputs can be specified in any base (binary, octal, decimal or hexadecimal).

The following are all equivalent:

```
A <= 10;
A <= 4'd10;
A <= 4'hA;
A <= 4'b1010;
```

If you want to only generate **valid BCD values** inputs in your testbench, you should generate the entire 4-digit number as an integer and then convert each digit to the appropriate bits to drive your design.

For example, to drive every valid value for input `A` (0 to 9999) you could do the following:

```
integer a;
for (a = 0; a < 10000; a = a + 1) begin

  // a is an integer
  // A is a 16-bit, 4-digit BCD value

  A[3:0] = a % 10;            // digit 0, ones place
  A[7:4] = (a / 10) % 10;     // digit 1, tens place
  A[11:8] = (a / 100) % 10;   // digit 2, hundreds place
  A[15:12] = (a / 1000) % 10; // digit 3, thousands place

end
```

For sampling the output, you would do the inverse - convert 4 4-bit BCD digits to an integer.

Here is a full, runnable example which includes code for sampling and verifying the output: http://www.edaplayground.com/x/2pT

Comment: @Dwikle no am using vi editor in unix.I have used for loop to generate input values.input values will be hexadecimal by default so I have to convert them to decimal,resulting decimal result will be converted into hexadecimal to check the condition I have mentioned above.

Comment: its a 16 bit bcd adder not 4 bit

Comment: @user3331420 I updated my answer after understanding better what you were asking. I don't see what vi has to do with anything... if you want to loop and generate values that should be coded in the testbench.

Comment: @dwikle...The link which you have mentioned is not opening.How can i write the above code as function

Answer (score 0):

I got it. I can write it using following function

```
function integer hexatodecimal;
 input [16:0] a; 
 integer b;
 begin
 b=a[3:0]+a[7:4]*10+a[11:8]*100+a[15:12]*1000+a[16]*10000;
 hexatodecimal=b;
 end
endfunction
```

I can call this function to convert `{Cout,S}` into hexadecimal.